# Forecasting in gretl

Tags: forecasting, gretl

Consider the following gretl script (hansl):

```
open bjg.gdt
arima 1 1 0 ; 2 1 0 ; g 
series fitted = $yhat
g1 <- gnuplot g fitted --with-lines --time-series --output=display
```

What I want to do next is to make a forecast for, lets say, 24 steps ahead, that is from Jan 1961 to Dec 1962. I believe the fifth line should be something like

```
fcast [options] --plot=display
```

What options to use here? I have tried several combinations but none is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further experimentation, here is the solution:

```
open bjg.gdt
arima 1 1 0 ; 2 1 0 ; g
series fitted = $yhat
g1 <- gnuplot g fitted --with-lines --time-series --output=display
dataset addobs 24
g2 <- fcast --dynamic --out-of-sample --plot=display
```